# One or more errors occurred.(An error occurred while sending the request) Mailchimp List Integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailchimp, dotnet-httpclient, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am developing a system that does the renewing of the subscription and sends the notification to the subscribers about their account activities. I implement Mailchimp to sends emails and notifications to the subscribers. I need to add lists to the Mailchimp and retrieve it to the system. I am getting an error while retrieving the lists from Mailchimp to the system. It says:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. An error occurred while sending the request.

Here is the code.

```
   protected void btnLoadList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            var gift = false;
            var combo = cboMailChimpLists;
            var text = txtChimpListNameID;
            if (button != null)
            {
                gift = button.ID == "btnRefreshListGift";
                if (gift)
                {
                    combo = cboMailChimpListsGift;
                    text = txtChimpListNameIDGift;
                }
            }
            var myList = new MailChimpList(txtChimpKey.Value);
            var test = myList.GetAllListsAsync();
            var testList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, MCLists>>();

            test.Wait(1000);      
      
            string reset = null;
            m_saveLists.Clear();
            if (test.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                combo.Items.Clear();

                foreach (var list in test.Result.lists)
                {
                    testList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, MCLists>(list.name, list));
                    if (IsNullOrEmpty(text.Value)) continue;

                    if (text.Value == list.id)
                        reset = list.name;
                }
            }
            int counter = 0;
            testList = testList.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
            foreach (var sort in testList)
            {
                combo.Items.Add(sort.Key);
                m_saveLists.Add(counter.ToString(), sort.Value.id);
                counter++;
            }
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(reset))
                combo.Text = reset;
            ViewState["SavedList"] = m_saveLists;
            if (combo.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(gift ? cboMailChimpListsGift : cboMailChimpLists, null);
            }
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            SiteToolKit.Tools.ExceptionHandler(ex, "btnLoadList_Click", lblError);
        }
    }
```

Error lists look like:

[image]

The issue occurs at `test.Wait()` method. I am unable to track more than this. But It works in some cases i.e. some clients. I have more than 100 clients and each client has their own and different products. It works for some clients and loads the list properly but in some clients, it occurs the error.

The working lists look like:

[image]

Is there anything I could change?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the security protocol:

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

before the

```
test.Wait();
```